# What would happen if an electron also had a positive charge?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, atomic-physics, charge, coulombs-law

**In an hydrogen atom, consisting of a proton and an electron, the electrostatic force between them is → *8.25 × 10−8 N***.

What would happen if the electron also had a positive charge with it.

> The force here is empirical. It can also be calculated otherwise.

Comment: Well for one thing there would be no-one to ask silly questions to.

Comment: Can you just answer it? I'm a laymen and it's really a good question for me right now.

Comment: No atoms could form.  No atoms, no people, no one to see what would happen.  The nucleus and electrons have to have opposite charges or they cannot form a stable system.

Comment: The simplest (and in my opinion, most correct) answer is *A is A - a thing is what it is and not what it isn't*.  An 'electron' with positive charge is *not* an electron but, rather, something else *by definition*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an open-ended, hypothetical "What if" type question that are [explicitly off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Well, that's rude! Everything originated from philosophy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An electron with a positive charge is known as a positron. It would fly out from the hydrogen atom, because it would be repelled by the proton. Eventually it would collide with something negatively charged (likely an electron) and annihilate and create energy equal to 2(Me)C^2, where Me is the mass of an electron.

Answer (score -2):

If electron also had a positive charge then it would cancel out the negative charge. It would mean the electron would be neutral and there would be nothing to bind them to the atoms thus all atoms will become ions. Chemistry wouldn't work any more without molecular binding. It would be the end of the world as we know it.